# construct an small app using shiny, after i code a loop it keeps giving me error

Tags: loops, shiny

construct an small app using shiny, after i code a loop it keeps giving me error

Why am I getting this error"evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?"

```
library(shiny)
ui<-fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "S0",label = "price at time 0",value = 20),
  numericInput(inputId = "k",label = "exercise price",value = 20),
  numericInput(inputId = "N",label = "steps",value = 50),
  numericInput(inputId = "r",label = "riskfree rate",value = 0.03),
  numericInput(inputId = "t",label = "time to exercise data",value = 1),
   plotOutput(outputId = "v")
)

server<-function(input,output)
{

  ve<-reactive({vector(mode="numeric",length=input$N+1)})
  ve<-reactive({rep(input$N,9)})


  for(i in 1:10)   
  {
    ve<-reactive({c(ve(),i)})
  }

 output$v<-renderPlot({plot(ve())})

}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

it seems that something wrong with the for() sentence

Comment: can you simply write your code in`r` as I dont understand what it is you;re trying to do

Comment: you have a variable `ve` receiving reactives a lot of times... you should probably read the documents on reactivity http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html